# Can't Kill Docker Main Process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, aws

***How do I kill the docker main process? Why does it keep crashing?***

I have docker installed on Ubuntu (on AWS).

I started a cluster the other day, and let it run over night. (It appeared to start with no issues.)

Returning the next day, I did a `docker ps`:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

So I `tail -f /var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 14 11:25:20 server01 kernel: [8107974.094867] init: docker main process (23915) terminated with status 1
Jul 14 11:25:20 server01 kernel: [8107974.094876] init: docker main process ended, respawning
Jul 14 11:25:21 server01 kernel: [8107975.451554] init: docker main process (23961) terminated with status 1
Jul 14 11:25:21 server01 kernel: [8107975.451564] init: docker main process ended, respawning
```

And the syslog looks like this, for hours.

And so I try `me@server01:~$ sudo sysctl docker stop`:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/docker: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/stop: No such file or directory
```

Then I try `me@server01:~$ sudo service docker stop`:

```
docker stop/waiting
```

Then `sudo service docker start`:

```
docker start/running, process 11150
```

And `tail -f /var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 14 11:35:13 server01 kernel: [8108567.403154] init: docker main process (11082) terminated with status 1
Jul 14 11:36:46 server01 kernel: [8108660.693572] init: docker main process (11150) terminated with status 1
Jul 14 11:36:46 server01 kernel: [8108660.693581] init: docker main process ended, respawning
Jul 14 11:36:48 server01 kernel: [8108662.068454] init: docker main process (11200) terminated with status 1
Jul 14 11:36:48 server01 kernel: [8108662.068463] init: docker main process ended, respawning
```

Thinking myself clever, I `sudo kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /var/run/docker.pid)` then...

```
sudo kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /var/run/docker.pid)
sudo kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /var/run/docker.pid)
sudo kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /var/run/docker.pid)
```

Just for good measure... and yet:

```
me@server01:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jul 14 11:56:07 server01 kernel: [8109821.948151] init: docker main process (17416) terminated with status 1
Jul 14 11:56:07 server01 kernel: [8109821.948160] init: docker main process ended, respawning
Jul 14 11:56:09 server01 kernel: [8109823.340658] init: docker main process (17469) terminated with status 1
Jul 14 11:56:09 server01 kernel: [8109823.340666] init: docker main process ended, respawning
```

And so forth... ***So I'm back to where I began.***

---

Unfortunately, `systemctl: command not found`

---

`docker run hello-world`:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `systemctl` command, not `sysctl`.

```
systemctl stop docker
```

If you want to stop it from starting at boot:

```
systemctl disable docker
```

Comment: Unfortunately `systemctl: command not found`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?
You may also want to add the line `DOCKER_OPTS="--debug=true --log-level=debug` to `/etc/default/docker`.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but uname -a outputs: `Linux server 3.13.0-91-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 17:00:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/os-release` or `cat /etc/lsb-release`.

Comment: Excuse me, lsb_release -a tells me it's 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: And I went ahead and edited `/etc/default/docker` like you recommended

Comment: It's using Upstart. Try `initctl stop docker`, although that ends up being executed when you do `service docker stop`. To disable at boot, `echo "manual" >> /etc/init/docker.override`. Once you start it again, hopefully there are debug messages in `/var/log/syslog` that lead you to why the process is/was constantly respawning.